How to record returned bank transfer
I have a situation where a bank transfer was attempted but failed probably because of wrong account info. Now, on the bank statement, I have a debit for the amount and a credit for the amount being returned. Later I have an identical debit for when the transfer went through successfully.
How do I record the original debit and the credit for the return in double entry accounting? Obviously they should not be counted as profit and loss.
Thanks!
P.S. Just to be extra clear how do I record the transactions on 6/1 and 6/2 below:
6/1/2024: -$1000  <-- attempted transfer
6/2/2024: $1000   <--- bank returned the money because the transfer failed
6/15/2024: -$1000 <--- transfer went through successfully

For your 6/1/2024 transaction, you made two entries (and again on 6/15/2024).  I would have thought your 6/2/2024 transaction should mirror the 6/1/2024 transaction, just with the signs reversed.

Thanks. I guess I'm asking what accounts to use. Normally the debit would be assigned to an expense account and the credit in an income account but then it would skew my profit and loss for those accounts. Should I assign the "income" on 6/2 to the expense account used in for 6/1?

This is called "reversing entries" and is easy to search for.  Whatever account you debited on 6/1/2024 should be credited on 6/2/2024, and whatever account you credited on 6/1/2024 should be debited on 6/2/2024.

Ah okay. Thank you so much! I'm still new at this and didn't know what terms to search for.

Thanks to Henry for the answer: "This is called "reversing entries" and is easy to search for. Whatever account you debited on 6/1/2024 should be credited on 6/2/2024, and whatever account you credited on 6/1/2024 should be debited on 6/2/2024."
